# Mezclar nombres y apellidos aleatorios en php

Tags: php, array, funciones, revisión-de-código

Tengo 3 arrays:

```
$nombres = array("Pepe", "Carlos", "Jesús", "Lola", "Rosa", "Maria");
$apellidos1 = array("Martin", "Lopez", "Salas", "Mateo", "Abas", "De Diego");
$apellidos2 = array("Quesada", "Alcala", "Marín", "Suarez", "Cobos","Rios");
```

y quiero crear un tercero que mezcle nombres y apellidos de forma aleatoria, he probado a meter la función `mt_rand` en los índices pero no me los hace bien, tampoco he conseguido con funciones que hagan este tipo de mezclas. No me lanza error, pero el array me muestra:

> Nombre aleatorio 3apellido aleatorio 0segundo apellido aleatorio 5

Mi código actual:

```
<?php

$nombres = array("Pepe", "Carlos", "Jesús", "Lola", "Rosa", "Maria");
$apellidos1 = array("Martin", "Lopez", "Salas", "Mateo", "Abas", "De Diego");
$apellidos2 = array("Quesada", "Alcala", "Marín", "Suarez", "Cobos","Rios");

$randn = array_rand($nombres,5);
$radn2 = array_rand($apellidos1,5);
$rand3 = array_rand($apellidos2,5);
echo "Nombre aleatorio ". $randn[mt_rand(0,5)]. "apellido aleatorio ".$radn2[mt_rand(0,5)]."segundo apellido aleatorio ".$rand3[mt_rand(0,5)];
?>
```

Comment: Solo quieres imprimir un valor aleatorio de esos array por la pantalla cierto? cuando dices de que "quieres crear un tercero", hablas de algo que devuelva los valores aleatorios? o un array mas que contenga valores aleatorios de esos 3 arrays que declaraste?

Comment: He leido tu comentario tarde, sólo quiero imprimir un valor aleatorio de los arrays

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No necesitas pasar, en el segundo parámetro, el largo del array. Ese valor lo deduce `array_rand` por sí mismo.

El efecto de pasar un número N distinto a 1 al segundo parámetro de array_rand, es que obtendrás como respuesta arreglo de N posiciones al azar. Si le pasas un 1 u omites el parámetro, te va a devolver un entero, que creo es lo que estás buscando.

```
<?php

$nombres = array("Pepe", "Carlos", "Jesús", "Lola", "Rosa", "Maria");
$apellidos1 = array("Martin", "Lopez", "Salas", "Mateo", "Abas", "De Diego");
$apellidos2 = array("Quesada", "Alcala", "Marín", "Suarez", "Cobos","Rios");

$randn = array_rand($nombres);
$radn2 = array_rand($apellidos1);
$rand3 = array_rand($apellidos2);
echo "Nombre aleatorio ". $nombres[$randn] 
    ." apellido aleatorio ". $apellidos1[$radn2] 
    ." segundo apellido aleatorio ". $apellidos2[$rand3];
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya decía yo que algo no cuadraba con el parámetro